# PostgreSQL management and monitoring

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql

Moving from Oracle to PostgreSQL, what (preferably free/OSS) software/tools are available that replace Oracle Enterprise Manager? I'm aware of pgAdmin, as well as some tools bundled into EnterpriseDB's Postgres Plus AS, but am looking for more context and a better overview of the PostgreSQL ecosystem.

Specifically I'm interested in tools to help:

- Alert db administrators to problems with both configuration and performance
- Monitoring of overall system performance
- General performance tuning
- Hinting support (my understanding is that PostgreSQL typically frowns on hinting)
- Disk management (ease in growth)
- Backup/restore beyond pg_dump and pg_restore

Any thoughts? This seems like something lots of folks may have been through before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postgres comes with excellent command-line tools, and they're the focus of the core developer team. I personally leverage those via custom site-specific scripts for db admin, upgrade, replication. For monitoring I use nagios to script psql to query vitals.

That said, there are some other options on the GUI-side beyond pgAdmin:

[SQL Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/postgresql/maestro/)

[phppgadmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/)

I don't think any of these have all of the features you listed, but they might be a good jumping off point. I doubt you will find an open source tool that really competes head-to-head with Oracle Enterprise Manager. On the commercial-side, there are also additional options:

[Navicat](http://pgsql.navicat.com/)

[RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/index.html?adid=ria14&gclid=CPOfu4SO5JgCFQkzawodVD1icA)

[MS SQL Manager for PostgreSQL](http://www.ems-hitech.com/pgmanager)

This wiki page also has links to many other postgres tools:

[Community Guide to PostgreSQL GUI Tools](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools)

Being a CLI-zealot myself I cannot given any specific recommendations but hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

From the management tool perspective caseman has already compiled a nice list, the PostgreSQL wiki also has a few additional ones on their [GUI Database Design Tools](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/GUI_Database_Design_Tools) page.

For Monitoring/Tuning it's a bit more complicated, there are many tools but no thorough solution. I started compiling a list, again in the Postgres Wiki: [Monitoring tools](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Monitoring).

Being unhappy with the status quo I teamed up with a colleague and we started working on our own solution called [`pganalyze`](https://pganalyze.com/), trying to help (parttime-)DBAs to understand what's going on in the database. But we also can only focus on a small subset of the problem area for the time being...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best site to search for software that fits your need would be PgFoundry: http://pgfoundry.org/

I don't think there is a software that fits all your needs but maybe you can combine some tools to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using some free gui tools but none of it can compare with Navicat PostgreSQL GUI. I think it's the Cat Pajamas!

they've a free version now, http://www.navicat.com.

martinlee